# Is Hive external table data distributed to data nodes in the same way as internal tables?

Tags: hadoop, hive, external-tables

I can't find reference information to explain certain details of Hive external tables. When a file located outside the default data warehouse is loaded to an external table (using LOCATION), is the data ingested and distributed among the data nodes as is the case with internal tables -- and the file used as the source remains intact in the file system, which essentially duplicates the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data are already in HDFS, there is no duplication. [An EXTERNAL table points to any HDFS location for its storage...](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExternalTables)

Comment: I think I've got it. I did a hadoop put to write the file to HDFS, then loaded to external table. The put command, writing to HDFS, distributes the data to the data nodes, just as loading an internal table ingests the data to HDFS. It's the HDFS FS abstraction that throws me...

Answer (score 0):

"External" means external to the default directory that Hive is using to store data (e.g., on Hortonworks it is /apps/hive/warehouse). It doesn't mean it is on the local filesystem - it must be on HDFS, on the same Hadoop cluster that Hive is pointing to.

Since it is HDFS data, Hive queries on it is treated exactly the same as if you had written a mapreduce job operating on that data directly. That is to say, it is not copied to /apps/hive/warehouse before hive will operate on it. Functionally the only difference is that if you DROP TABLE an external table, the data is not deleted from HDFS. Other than that, everything else works exactly the same for internal vs external tables.

Comment: Thanks Simplefish. My external table LOCATION is on an NFS mount to the Hadoop cluster Hive is pointed to. I assume that any NFS mounts are recognized as local to the cluster without needing to be specified in the Hadoop config?

Answer (score 0):

> An EXTERNAL table points to any HDFS location for its storage, rather
>   than being stored in a folder specified by the configuration property
>   `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir`(Location of default database for the warehouse).

**The data is not replicated when you make an external table.** So, when dropping an EXTERNAL table, data in the table is not deleted from the file system.

***Note: Even in case of internal tables data is NOT distributed among the nodes, the data is replicated based on the replication factor***.